# can't install mu-editor

Tags: python3

The os and python version:

```
uname -a
Linux yyyy 4.19.0-0.bpo.9-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.118-2+deb10u1~bpo9+1 (2020-06-09) x86_64 GNU/Linux

python3 -V
Python 3.5.3
```

My microbit version:

```
Interface Version: 0255
Bootloader Version: 0255
```

Install mu-editor

```
sudo pip3 install mu-editor
Collecting mu-editor
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fa/2f/6f7eb7e836a528d6959e5c79491d90faef2df7a78e9d953b84451551a98e/mu_editor-1.0.3-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pyflakes==2.0.0 (from mu-editor)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/44/98/af7a72c9a543b1487d92813c648cb9b9adfbc96faef5455d60f4439aa99b/pyflakes-2.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting guizero>=1.1.0 (from mu-editor)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/88/36/52ae98723d83fed0c6496f8e42cf2b2ae37c7218fc43545394321be9fd3d/guizero-1.1.1-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pyserial==3.4 (from mu-editor)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0d/e4/2a744dd9e3be04a0c0907414e2a01a7c88bb3915cbe3c8cc06e209f59c30/pyserial-3.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (193kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 194kB 341kB/s 
Collecting qscintilla==2.11.4 (from mu-editor)
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement qscintilla==2.11.4 (from mu-editor) (from versions: 2.9.2, 2.9.3, 2.9.4, 2.10, 2.10.1, 2.10.2, 2.10.3, 2.10.4, 2.10.7, 2.10.8, 2.11, 2.11.1, 2.11.2, 2.11.3)
No matching distribution found for qscintilla==2.11.4 (from mu-editor)
```

Comment: How is the micro-bit involved?

Answer (score 2):

For readers using Debian 10 or later, or Ubuntu 20.04 or later, or a derivative:

```
sudo apt install mu-editor
```

will install the editor and its dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo  pip3  install pyqt5     
sudo -H pip3 install mu-editor
```

Answer (score 0):

[`mu-editor`](https://snapcraft.io/install/mu-editor/ubuntu) is packaged as a snap:

```
sudo snap install mu-editor --edge
```

Comment: ... but it hasn’t been updated since November 2018 and provides an older version of the editor than the Debian package :-(.

Comment: @StephenKitt Just to say there are a many way to install the package. I prefer the `apt` way.